# Oracle sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-x64 key constraint declaration

Tags: sql, oracle

I've started working with Oracle. I'm using sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-x64 and using the GUI for creating the table. Now for a table I've to declare three attrbutes(ID.BANK_NAME,BANK_EMAIL) as Unique key. I can declare primary key from the table menu. I'm now stuck with this specific task of declaring the unique key.Is there any way to do it without using the script?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the table by clicking on it -> Constraints -> Actions -> Constraint -> Add Unique...

[image]

Comment: Are you in Oracle Database? No enum datatype in Oracle AFAI. You should check this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81759/add-enum-attribute-to-existing-table-using-alter

Comment: Anyway if this question is answered you should mark it as such

Comment: Is there any problem with version of oracle database. Can't find no such thing like on delete cascade in GUI

Comment: I don't see it either, you should raise a new question. I insist, if your initial question is answered you should mark it as such.